# child_process nodejs doesn't fire error if file doesn't exists

Tags: node.js, spawn

I should exec a VBS script by **Nodejs** and so I'm using **child_process**.

My problem is that if there is an error on spawn process it never fires error event.

```
const { spawn } = require( 'child_process' );

const vbs = spawn( 'cscript.exe', [ vbsPath] );
vbs.on('error', function( err ){
   console.log(err);
})
vbs.on('close', async function(code) {
   console.log(code)
});
```

**vbsPath** is the path of vbs and if I try to put wrong path or add an error in vbs it fires always **close** event with code 1 instead of 0. 
but my question is:

Why it never fires the error event? Is the **code** of close event reliable for know if the script return error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is spawned well, it is due to this that you don't receive the error.

From [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_error)

> The 'error' event is emitted whenever:
>
> The process could not be spawned, or
>
> The process could not be killed, or
>
> Sending a message to the child process failed.

For example, if you write `const vbs = spawn('ciao', ['vbsPath'])` you will receive the error event.

Comment: But if I put a wrong path how the spawn doesn't return error?

Comment: The process `cscript` start correctly, the wrong path is a problem of that process, in fact you have the `return code` in the close. The error event is to manage when a process doesn't start (or communicate) not to receive "bad error codes" because you could manage return code 1 as OK (it is your choice).

Comment: Oh thank you, so I can use both the code and the error event, for get all the errors cases, right?

Comment: Yes, you can manage the `error` event like a fatal-error, and the `close with code > 0` as normal errors